# How do I specify custom frequency in Aviarc Scheduler

Tags: cron, aviarc

I just noticed that the scheduled workflow runner in Aviarc now has a 'Custom' frequency.

How do I specify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available workflow scheduling options are Daily, Weekly, Monthly or Cron. So you can set custom schedule frequencies using [Cron syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples). In the scheduling panel there's also a syntax guide and a button to check the validity of your pattern.